# Dispatch on tagged union

Tags: c, struct, switch-statement, unions

I am using C tagged-union style structures to represent AST nodes. They look like this:

```
struct A_var_ {
  enum {
    A_simpleVar,
    A_fieldVar,
    A_subscriptVar
  } kind;

  A_pos pos;

  union {
    S_symbol simple;

    struct {
      A_var var;
      S_symbol sym;
    } field;

    struct {
      A_var var;
      A_exp exp;
    } subscript;
  } u;
};
```

Now, I am trying to dispatch on the type of the node, like this:

```
switch(node->kind) {
  case A_simpleVar:
    ...
}
```

However, I'm getting errors like `Can't resolve variable A_simpleVar`. How can I achieve this? I'm using Cmake on windows, and the compiler is gcc.

The specific errors I am getting, for the following code:

```
struct expty transExp(S_table venv, S_table tenv, A_exp a)
{
  switch (a->kind) {
    case A_letExp:
      struct expty exp;
      A_decList d;
      S_beginScope(venv);
      S_beginScope(tenv);
      for (d = a->u.let.decs; d; d=d->tail) {
        transDec(venv, tenv, d->head);
      }
      exp = transExp(venv, tenv, a->u.let.body);
      S_endScope(tenv);
      S_endScope(venv);
      return exp;

    case A_opExp:
      A_oper oper = a->u.op.oper;
      struct expty left = transExp(venv, tenv, a->u.op.left);
      struct expty right = transExp(venv, tenv, a->u.op.right);
      if (oper == A_plusOp) {
        if (left.ty->kind != Ty_int)
          EM_error(a->u.op.left->pos, "integer required");
        if (right.ty->kind != Ty_int)
          EM_error(a->u.op.right->pos, "integer required");
        return expTy(NULL, Ty_Int());
      } // I need to cover other operators as well, but not for prototype
  }
}
```

are:

`C:\Users\Fotis\Documents\Devel\grimoire\Books\ModernCompilerC\semant.c: In function 'transExp':
C:\Users\Fotis\Documents\Devel\grimoire\Books\ModernCompilerC\semant.c:28:7: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
       struct expty exp;
       ^
C:\Users\Fotis\Documents\Devel\grimoire\Books\ModernCompilerC\semant.c:29:7: error: expected expression before 'A_decList'
       A_decList d;
       ^
C:\Users\Fotis\Documents\Devel\grimoire\Books\ModernCompilerC\semant.c:32:12: error: 'd' undeclared (first use in this function)
       for (d = a->u.let.decs; d; d=d->tail) {`

It might also be important to note that the parameters to the functions are pointers to the structs that are `typedef`ed. I.e an `A_exp` is an `A_exp_ *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what the problem was some time ago, but just found the time to point it out so others can get helped in case they fall into the same error.

The thing to notice here is the compiler error:

`C:\Users\Fotis\Documents\Devel\grimoire\Books\ModernCompilerC\semant.c: In function 'transExp':
C:\Users\Fotis\Documents\Devel\grimoire\Books\ModernCompilerC\semant.c:28:7: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
       struct expty exp;`

For some reason, in the C grammar, a declaration is considered an `expression`, and the syntax of the C grammar requires a statement as a body of a `case`. The easiest way to make a series of expressions/statements into just one statement is to enclose them all in brackets. In this particular case, the way to go would be translating the erroneous code in the question into:

```
(...snip...)

switch (a->kind) {
    case A_letExp: {
      struct expty exp;
      A_decList d;
      S_beginScope(venv);
      S_beginScope(tenv);
      for (d = a->u.let.decs; d; d=d->tail) {
        transDec(venv, tenv, d->head);
      }
      exp = transExp(venv, tenv, a->u.let.body);
      S_endScope(tenv);
      S_endScope(venv);
      return exp;
    }
```

Notice the symbols `{` and `}` after `case A_letExp:` and after `return exp;`.

Answer (score 3):

You're compiling with a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.  The two handle enums differently.

In C, all enums are visible at the global scope.  In C++, they are qualified by the containing type, if any.  So you need to prefix the enum values with the struct name:

```
switch(node->kind) {
  case A_var_::A_simpleVar:
    ...
}
```

Comment: While you're right in this answer of yours, I mentioned that I was using `g++` but that was a mistake. It appears I am using `gcc` instead. Let me update the question with more details on the specific errors